# Trying to make an Recipe post in sailsjs

Tags: mysql, model, controller, sails.js, backend

I am trying to make a website where you can post recipes. I am unsure how to set up the models and controllers. for my database I want to set it up the the post_title,post_description are one table. post_category another table, and ingredients a third table. how do I set it up that when submiting a form it goes to all these tables. (I am more of a front end guy trying to learn back end stuff). I can easily do this in one model of course but how do I split it off. one to many relationships I am sure but they are kinda confusing me. I am using sailsjs with mysql. any help would be greatly appriciated.

Here is my post model as of now.

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
  post_title: {
  type: 'string',
  required: true
},

post_description: {
type: 'string',
  required: true
},

post_category: {
type: 'string',
  required: true
},
}
};
```

and my form

```
<form action="/post/create" method="post" class="register-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label>Title</label>
  <input name="post_title" style="width: 40em;" class="form-control" type="text">
  <label>Description</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" name="post_description" style="width: 40em; height: 10em"></textarea>
  <label>Category</label>
  <select name="post_category" class="form-control" style="width: 40em;">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="oven">Oven</option>
    <option value="no_bake">No Bake</option>
    <option value="bbq">Bbq</option>
    <option value="slow_cook">Slow Cooker</option>
  </select>
  <label>Ingredient 1</label>
  <input name="ingredient_1" style="width: 40em;" class="form-control" type="text">
  <label>Ingredient 2</label>
  <input name="ingredient_2" style="width: 40em;" class="form-control" type="text">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default " value="Submit Post">
</form>
```

and my create

```
 create: function (req, res, next) {
    Post.create( req.params.all(), function postCreated(err, post) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.redirect('/post/show/' + post.id);
    });
  },
```

Comment: No one is gonna go to the link and read your code. Please read [how to ask.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Your right. My apologizes. I edited it to explain best I could

Answer (score 0):

In controller:

1. Create `Post` using parameter which belong to `Post` i.e. `post_title`, `post_description` etc.
2. In callback on `Post.create`, create `Ingredient`

Similarly for `post_category` if it is to be stored in a different model. It looks part of `Post` model as per your code.

Comment: Does this resolve your query? If yes, please accept.